# Depth and collision with ennemies

Tags: flash, actionscript

Once again I got a question.

I've simplified my game to make it on time. However, I still have a major problem; the flashlight. I would like it to mask everything else except where it's actually aimed.

Still not able to make the collisions too.

http://ifile.it/xmhra7g

Sorry for being annoying with my questions.
(should I edit when I have new questions or keep on posting new ones?)

Thanks, Mathieu.

Comment: If your new question is closely related to an old one I'd suggest editing it. When you've edited a question it will appear at the top of the homepage again, so it's just as effective as posting a new one. The advantage of editing is that people can see your entire problem and provide an answer that properly covers what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you Marty Wallace.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are looking for a way to make a mask follow your mouse cursor? Here is a pretty good example in AS3: http://www.schoolofflash.com/2008/03/tutorial-actionscript-30-masks/

As for collision detection, this is a very common question for Flash. Googling "flash collision detection" should do the trick.

Happy coding.